# VBA macro to find if a value in a cell is within the range of the values of two cells

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have 2 sheets. Sheet1 has 3 columns A, B & C with values of range_start_number (A), range_end_number (B) and range_name (C).

Sheet2 has 1 column A with the list of numbers.

How to find which numbers in sheet2 belong to which ranges in sheet1? In addition, also,  the number's position within a corrosponding range. The output should be:
 'range name'-'position in range'

see below for example data inputs (sheet1 & sheet2) and expected output (in sheet2).

```
    Sheet1  (input) 
A   B   C
10  17  rangeA
17  15  rangeB
30  12  rangeC
8   9   rangeD
11  9   rangeE
36  50  rangeF
40  45  rangeG
31  32  rangeH
5   25  rangeI
25  26  rangeJ

Sheet2 (input)
A
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
22
23
24
25



 Sheet2 (output)            
A   B   C   D   E
10  rangeA-1    rangeI-6      rangeE-2
11  rangeA-2    rangeI-7      rangeE-1
12  rangeA-3    rangeC-19   rangeI-8    
13  rangeA-4    rangeC-18   rangeI-9    
14  rangeA-5    rangeC-17   rangeI-10   
15  rangeA-6    rangeB-3    rangeC-16   rangeI-11
16  rangeA-7    rangeB-2    rangeC-15   rangeI-12
17  rangeA-8    rangeB-1    rangeC-14   rangeI-13
18  rangeC-13   rangeI-14       
19  rangeC-12   rangeI-15       
22  rangeC-9    rangeI-18       
23  rangeC-8    rangeI-19       
24  rangeC-7    rangeI-20       
25  rangeC-6    rangeI-21   rangeJ-1
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  And include the code you are trying to work through...so people can help.

Comment: Why does 10 belong to rangeI-6 twice? What does the -6 mean?

Comment: I have edited the question. That was a mistake.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The number's position within the range is calculated subtracting the lesser of the ranges' numbers from the input value

```
Sub RangeSub()
  Row = 1
  Do While True
    Column = 6
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(Row, 5)) Then
      rRow = 1
      Do While True
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(rRow, 1)) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(rRow, 2)) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(rRow, 3)) Then
          If (Cells(rRow, 1).Value <= Cells(Row, 5).Value And Cells(Row, 5).Value <= Cells(rRow, 2).Value) Or (Cells(rRow, 1).Value >= Cells(Row, 5).Value And Cells(Row, 5).Value >= Cells(rRow, 2).Value) Then
            Position = Abs(Cells(Row, 5) - Cells(rRow, 1)) + 1
            Cells(Row, Column).Value = Cells(rRow, 3).Value + "-" + Str(Position)
            Column = Column + 1
          End If
        Else
          Exit Do
        End If
        rRow = rRow + 1
      Loop
      Row = Row + 1
    Else
      Exit Do
    End If
  Loop
End Sub
```

The code works with the ranges and input in the same sheet, you could change it to work in different sheets.

```
A   B   C      D    E
10  17  rangeA      10
17  15  rangeB      11
30  12  rangeC      12
8   9   rangeD      13
11  9   rangeE      14
36  50  rangeF      15
40  45  rangeG      16
31  32  rangeH      17
5   25  rangeI      18
25  26  rangeJ      19
                    22
                    23
                    24
                    25
```

*D is blank.*

Comment: Thanks . It worked. Except the 'position' of a number in a range would always be from the range start. If 'range_start' >='number' then abs(range_start-number)+1 else (number-range_start)+1 end

Comment: @user3531676 Edited the code to make the operation that way, deleted the Min function and changed the line that makes the operation to just `Position = Abs(Cells(Row, 5) - Cells(rRow, 1)) + 1` If this solves your answer, please accept it.

Comment: All good. just a little issue in line 10 of your code. the 'position' repeated. I have fixed it.